# Select and update mysql same query php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Hello i am trying to do combine UPDATE and SELECT statement in one query.

This is the one i tried. but didnt work.

```
$this->$db2->query('
  UPDATE users
  SET total = (total - (
    SELECT floatingnumber
    FROM posts
    WHERE post_id = "'.$this->post_id.'"
    LIMIT 1
  ))
  WHERE id = "'.$this->post_user->id.'"
  LIMIT 1
');
```

Comment: i think LIMIT is not allowed in subquery in mysql, might be untrue but check if your query is even valid and executing

Comment: @HankyPanky: That's correct.  `LIMIT` does not work in [subqueries](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/subquery-restrictions.html).

Comment: also can't update/delete from a table which you're selecting from.

Comment: @RocketHazmat There is a work around IIRC: `... (SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM whatever) AS alias LIMIT 1) ...` - basically if you wrap the query in another sub query and give the inner query an alias then `LIMIT` magically works again (on the outer query). Go figure.

Comment: i want to select then update

Comment: You should use a JOIN instead of a subquery.  Is there a link between `posts` and `users`?

Comment: This looks like a job for a transaction to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one with `INNER JOIN` , without `SELECT`

```
UPDATE users u 
INNER JOIN posts p
ON  // realationship between tables
 SET total = total - p.floatingnumber

WHERE p.post_id = "'.$this->post_id.'"

AND  u.id = "'.$this->post_user->id.'"

 LIMIT 1
```